# Setup iOS Coda to clone a repository from GitHub

Tags: ios, github, coda

I've been learning web development and I would like to work on a website (HTML, CSS, JS) and its files using Coda on the iPad. I would like to clone the repository, make changes, and push it back to GitHub. The app includes FTP but I'm unable to understand how to link GitHub

Comment: Sounds like a question for [Panic support](https://panic.com/coda-ios/#help).

Comment: For reference, Panic responded that the iOS version doesn't support this function. However, Coda for Mac does support this obviously.

Comment: If you want to clone git repos on iOS, [Working Copy](http://workingcopyapp.com) might be what you need.